# BigQuery not returning any rows with --max_rows set to large value

Tags: google-bigquery

When using the `bq` command line tool, if I set `--max_rows` to a large number, nothing is being returned.

I am trying to use the `bq` command line tool to gather data. I have my query mapped out, now I just need to be able to programmatically return the results in a script. I want to do something similar to the following:

```
cat query_file | bq --bigqueryrc=/path/to/file --format=json --headless -q query --use_legacy_sql=false --max_rows=100000 > /path/to/file.json
```

The above query works fine on my local machine, however, when I try to run the same query with a Service Account nothing is outputted to the file.

If I set `--max_rows` to something smaller, like 1000, the query will work and return 1000 rows. But it will not return anything when set to a large value like 10,000.

Is there something different about Service Accounts that would impact the `--max_rows` setting? I can't for the life of my figure out why it works fine locally, but not with the Service Account.

*Extra Info*

- Local Machine is OSX using `bq` from the gcloud command line tools, BigQuery CLI 2.0.40.
- Machine the Service Account is running on is Ubuntu 18.04 using `bq` from the gcloud command line tools, BigQuery CLI 2.0.40.

*Edit*

I was able to use the Service Account locally and have it work correctly with `--max_rows` so the issue appears to be specific to the environment that the query is running in.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! I was running the `bq` command in a Kubernetes Pod, and the process was being silently killed because of memory constraints. Increasing the memory requests allowed for the command to complete successfully.